# Does IPC shared memory takes memory from heap?

Tags: c++, ipc

In my project I am using shared memory for data transfer from one process to another. Data would be huge because  those are the images. After running multiple times the process, I can see **shmat** failed. After deep investigation on the same, I can see there is some memory leaks in every cycling of the process. I just wonder if it could be reason for the failure??
Does IPC shared memory acquires the memory from heap?? Or what could be the other reason for failure of the same beacuse firt 10 cycling of the process run fine.

Comment: You need to provide some code: how do you create/map the shared memory in your process ? how do you release/unmap it ? It would also be useful if you precised the OS you are using (sounds Unixy to me), etc... as it stands, your question is too incomplete. (and the answer to the question is your title is: this does not make sense, at the machine level there is no heap, just memory).

Comment: I am running my application on 32 bin unix machine.   I simply use IPC API shmget, shmat APIs. I have two processes, one process write the images to sharedmemory and one tries to read and t uses shmat after doing a shmget through a key. After some cycling I can see shmat failed for some reason.

Comment: This is still too imprecise, please edit your question with the actual *code* so that we can see the *arguments* used in those functions. Those arguments determine what the actual effect of the call is.

Comment: Use the `ipcs -m` command to find out how many shared memory segments you have lingering from previous runs.  http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_ipcs.htm
 As @CTucker pointed out, these segments remain until you remove them, which you can do with the `ipcrm -m id` command. http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_ipcrm.htm

Answer (score 2):

Given your scenario (a process that runs multiple times, and fails after the tenth), I suspect that it is not related to a heap memory leak (which would be irrelevant after process exit).

It sounds like you are reaching a system imposed limit related to shared memory.  The most likely limits are either 1) a limit on the total number of shared memory segments, or 2) a limit on the total amount of shared memory.  This can be an issue if you create a segment each time your process runs, and fail to mark it for destruction with shmctl().

By default, when a process exits, it will automatically be detached from any attached shared memory; however, you must explicitly destroy the segment so that resources can be reclaimed after all process have detached.

Always check the return code/error indicators from system calls, and check the manpage(s) for the cause and potential resolution.